# How to find all id of elements that with one child element is visible

Tags: jquery

How to get all id of div.A that has div.collapse is visible,example:

```
<div class="A">
   <div id="1"></div>
   <div class="collapse"></div>
</div>
<div class="A">
   <div id="2"></div>
   <div class="collapse" style="display:none"></div>
</div>
<div class="A">
   <div id="3"></div>
   <div class="collapse"></div>
</div>
```

which i should get id 1 and 3.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/

Comment: @MattBall Sorry,I only tried .find to try to get an array of id, but I found it is impossible to get an array directly, then I know .each now, to loop each one, and manually push into array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the most concise way but

```
$('div.A div.collapse:visible').siblings('div').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

would work for the example you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('div.A div.collapse:visible').siblings('div').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('id'))
})​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/L62UP/)**.

Comment: You're right, console.log is probably a more reasonable generic example since we don't know how it's being used. +1 and edited my answer to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

$("div.A > div:first-child ~ .collapse:visible");

working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dfygrvty/xQdz5/)

this will select the   (first child of div.A) that have a sibling that is .collapse:visible.   jsfiddle throws some text in the divs.